# Подскажите "чек лист" безопасности веб приложения, по аналогии с django?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, golang, безопасность

Когда я делаю приложение на django у меня автоматически ругается если не включить CSRF или ALLOWED_HOST (host header attacks) тем самым джанга сама контролирует какой то базовый набор уязвимостей.

Сейчас я хочу сделать приложение на Reactjs на фронте и GO на беке как rest api, тем самым я буду просто принимать запросы и обрабатывать их.

Есть ли какой то чеклист или фреймворк для rest который так же как django будет просто по умолчанию заставлять настроить нужные параметры безопасности?
И поидеи на чьей это стороне должно быть все , на стороне бекап или фронта или и там и там?

Comment: Тут https://owasp.org куча информации по теме безопасности и уязвимостей в приложениях включая веб (https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten, https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide). Основные 10 уязвимостей версия 2017 года даже есть по-русски wiki.owasp.org/images/9/96/OWASP_Top_10-2017-ru.pdf

Comment: Это да, но это через чур сильно для простого сайта, но самое основное хочется настроить, поэтому и хотелось бы по аналогии с django как там чтобы совсем основное закрывалось